# How do I find a .php file that has a specific class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

How do I find a .php file that has a specific class?

I want to add a class to another class. I added a class to an existing class in inspector tools, but can´t find the .php file so I can add the class to it.

Wordpress/Woocommerce site.

Please help.

I tried to add classin inspector tool, it seems find. Now I want to save the changes, but need  to find the proper .php file to do se.

Comment: what "inspector tool" specifically are you referring to? Try to be specific. At the very least you should be  able to do a "Find" to locate the class name. E.g. search for `class YourClassName` in the code. If you don't have an IDE which search functionality then you could always use something like `grep` to search the PHP files.

Comment: Classes may be in part set directly in a template, but class names might also get gathered in some variable first, and then the value of that variable gets output in the template - in the latter case, you are rather unlikely to find the correct place via a simple search over your theme files. Perhaps you should start looking for the relevant template files based on what _type_ of content you are dealing with there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free String Locator plugin to search for strings directly in the WordPress admin panel.